# Ownership/borrowing issues when trying to get a DB connection and tx from a separate function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a common function that returns a MySQL connection:

```
pub fn get_db_conn() -> Result<PooledConn> {...}
```

And all around the application I have code like this:

```
let mut conn = get_db_conn()?;
let mut tx = conn.start_transaction(TxOpts::default())?;
```

That kinda breaks the DRY principle and I'd like to simplify that code by only having to call a *single* function. So I image something like this:

```
pub fn get_db_conn_and_tx() -> Result<(PooledConn, Transaction)> {
    let mut conn = get_db_conn()?;
    let mut tx = conn.start_transaction(TxOpts::default())?;
    Ok((conn, tx))
}
```

or this:

```
pub fn get_db_tx() -> Result<(Transaction)> {
    let mut conn = get_db_conn()?;
    let mut tx = conn.start_transaction(TxOpts::default())?;
    Ok((tx))
}
```

However, neither of those compiles.

Let's take the first one as an example. This is the error the compiler emits:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
   |
33 | pub fn get_db_conn_with_tx() -> Result<(PooledConn, Transaction)> {
   |                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime
   |
33 | pub fn get_db_conn_with_tx() -> Result<(PooledConn, Transaction<'static>)> {
   |                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried changing the result to `Result<(PooledConn, Transaction<'static>)>`. This time I got:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `conn`
   |
35 |     let mut tx = conn.start_transaction(TxOpts::default())?;
   |                  ---- `conn` is borrowed here
36 |     Ok((conn, tx))
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Why do I get that error message? I am returning *both* `conn` and `tx`, so shouldn't ownership of both values be transferred to the calling function?

Also, I wonder what would be the best way to implement the second function that returns just a `Transaction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this one:

```
fn tuple() -> (i32, &i32) {
    let x = 42;
    (x, &x)
}
```

That produces the same error message:

```
1 | fn tuple() -> (i32, &i32) {
  |                     ^ expected named lifetime parameter
```

This issue is called *"self referential structs"* (self referential tuple in your case, but the same concept), and is a persistent pain for many Rust users, because it does not have a full satisfactory solution.

There a bunch of third party crates that tackle this problem. My personal favorite is currently [`ouroboros`](https://crates.io/crates/ouroboros).

But if you just want to avoid typing two lines you can use a macro, not pretty, but it is short (you can add your database code instead of numbers):

```
macro_rules! self_ref {
    ($r:ident) => {
        let $r = 42;
        //Shadow the first variable, it is borrowed anyway
        let $r = &$r;
    }
}

fn main() {
    self_ref!(r);
    dbg!(r);
}
```

But for your particular case of a DB connection and a transaction, I don't think it is worth it, I would just use two variables and two function calls.

Comment: Thanks, Rodrigo! Very helpful again! I'm still quite new to Rust and the concept of a macro didn't even occur to me. Substituting the two lines with `start_tx!(tx);` (or `start_tx!(conn, tx);` if needed) would really help remove some boilerplate code. The only thing is, I'm not sure how good of an idea is to **declare** variables that way:? It's not as explicit as when using `let`.

Comment: @at54321: Rust macros are what they call _hygienic_, that is, they cannot inject names in the current scope that you do not write explicitly. This is why you need to pass the `tx` as an argument to the macro, it cannot be created inside, and it somehow limits the havoc that macros can create. IMO, public macros should have a nice syntax, and this is not; but private macros can do whatever you fancy. Just take a look at a few [private std macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/num/mod.rs.html#169).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. With power comes responsibility...